# Showering in the morning

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, showering-bathing

If a person showers right when they wake up, does it remove the impurity from their hands since a shower acts as a mikvah? Or do they still have to do washing from a vessel?

Comment: How do you know that "a shower acts as a mikvah"?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I'm not even sure that it qualifies for the 9 kabin

Comment: Seems like a shower might be more than 9 kabin. Google search about how much water is used... The average American shower uses 17.2 gallons (65.1 liters) and lasts for 8.2 minutes at average flow rate of 2.1 gallons per minute (gpm) (7.9 lpm).

Comment: I think you’re confusing two different topics. The reason we wash our hands in the morning is because of a concept of “ruach ra’ah,” which seems to have more to do with cleanliness than purity. So the fact that the shower acts as a Mikvah (which FWIW is only true by a Baal Keri - that’s the 9 Kav thing discussed in earlier comments. Normally you’re Tamei d’Rabbanan if you use a shower as a mikvah, just to demonstrate that it’s not one) doesn’t seem at all related to netilas yadayim. You could ask the same question as dipping your hands under a sink faucet.